# QGIS2web text labels not visible on the map

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

I want to have the text labels visible on my map.

Unfortunately, I don't know where is the error.

In both cases, the labels are based on one category. In one object I can see the label, in other not. When launch the map preview situation is opposite.

Doesn anyone know how to display the text labels in QGIs2web properly?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code in our _syle.js layer files we should replace the:

```
   if ("" !== null) {
    labelText = String("");
   }
```

with

```
   if (feature.get("Pole No.") !== null) {
    labelText = String(feature.get("Pole No."));
    }
```

and it will work

[image]

Comment: Also this could help: 
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269217/avoid-multiple-labels-for-the-same-layer-in-qgis2web-export/269222#269222

Comment: Are you sure, that your solution is correct? Because within your screenshot "P9" is not within the point....

Comment: As far as I am concerned I need the P9 to be visible at all. If you have a better solution, you can always suggest something different. I guess, that the alignment section in the code is "responsible" for that.

Comment: You could use own svg symbols. With inkscape you can create svg symbols. For example P1-P9. But with a perfect design. Sure, not for all projects a solution.

Comment: You could use svg openclipart. These free cliparts you can change for your project.
https://openclipart.org/detail/141541/numbers